# How may I integrate $I = \int_{0}^{a} f(x) x^2 dx $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, step-function

How may I integrate $I = \int_{0}^{10} f(x) x^2 dx $ where $f(x)$ is:

$$ \begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
   f_1, & x \in (0,8) ∪ (9,10)\\
    f_2, & x \in (8,9)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}  $$

EDIT: upper interval is 10, not $a$

Comment: Presumably $f_1$ and $f_2$ are constants? If so, just break your integral into its pieces. Of course there's an oddity with the fact that the upper limit of integration is $a$ which does not appear anywhere in the definition of $f$, so your answer will depend on $a$ in a nontrivial way.

Comment: Split the interval on sub intervals where $f$ is constant and sum the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f_1, f_2$ are constants, just consider all possible values for $a$.

1. If $a < 8$,
   $$\int_0^a f(x) x^2 dx = \int_0^a f_1 x^2 dx = \frac{f_1 a^3}{3}.$$
2. If $8 \leq a \leq 9$,
   $$
   \int_0^2 f(x) x^2 dx = \int_0^8 f_1 x^2 dx + \int_8^a f_2 x^2 dx = \frac{f_1 8^3}{3} + \left(\frac{f_2 a^3}{3}-\frac{f_2 8^3}{3}\right) = \frac 13 f_2 a^3+\left(f_1-f_2\right)\frac{512}{3}
   $$

I trust you can now deal with the case $a>9$.